# how to call static header and footer in more than one html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 5 html pages and all those pages have same header and footer

I need to reuse the header and footer in all the HTML pages

how effectively i can reuse them so as to avoid repititive codes?

Comment: I think you should go with php or any other frame work.

Comment: Check this http://phpsmashcode.com/tips-and-tricks/include-common-files-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a php include.
Put the html in a php file and save it eg. header.php

Then in your html you place a reference to the php file

```
<?php include ('includes/header.php'); ?>
```